# Can't use chmod or chown on AKS with Azure Blob NFS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, nfs

I have few scripts that are doing chmod on some files and those files have to abe accessible by other pods.
I decided to use Azure blob NFS(v3) and everything works fine but `chmod` is returning an error:

`chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs': Operation not permitted`

I do not know how can I fix that so `chmod` commands will work on files/directories which are mounted on NFS pv. Are there any special mounting attributes or this is not possible to do on Azure Blob NFS and I need to actualy setup proper NFS on Linux VM?

I've tried adding security context but it does not fixed anything(1000 is the id of user running the container)

```
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        runAsGroup: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
```

my pv:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: blob.csi.azure.com
  name: pv-blob
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Pi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain  
  storageClassName: azureblob-nfs-premium
  csi:
    driver: blob.csi.azure.com
    readOnly: false
    nodeStageSecretRef:
      name: azure-storage-blob
      namespace: default
    volumeHandle: "akstest"
    volumeAttributes:
      resourceGroup: testrg
      storageAccount: teststorage
      containerName: container
      protocol: nfs
```

pvc.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc-blob
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  volumeName: pv-blob
  storageClassName: azureblob-nfs-premium
```

Comment: Where you are executing the **chmod** command?

Comment: Chmod is executed from shell script which is mounted on that blob pv

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce this in my environment,I have created a AKS cluster and enabled  CSI driver.

```
az aks update --enable-blob-driver -n <aks-cluter-name> -g <resource-group-name>
```

https://i.imgur.com/t2vu6OO.png

Next I have created Storage account in the AKS node resource group with premium tier and enabled hierarchy and NFSv3 protocol.
https://i.imgur.com/Yx0oVZq.png
https://i.imgur.com/pVjzRhZ.png

Now I created storage class as below and reffered in PVC. Below are the manifest files I used to created PV and PVC and added as a volume to the pod.
**Storage-class:**

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: azureblob-nfs-premium
provisioner: blob.csi.azure.com
parameters:
  protocol: nfs
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

**Persistant-volume:**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: blob.csi.azure.com
  name: pv-blob
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: azureblob-nfs-premium
  csi:
    driver: blob.csi.azure.com
    readOnly: false
    volumeHandle: unique-volumeid
    volumeAttributes:
      resourceGroup: MC_v-goonav-mindtree_aksclusteringvjy_eastus
      storageAccount: strgblobakstest
      containerName: contianer01
      protocol: nfs
```

**Persistant-volume-claim:**

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc-blob
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  volumeName: pv-blob
  storageClassName: azureblob-nfs-premium
```

Now I created sample pod and verified whenter the files are accessible.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: 
spec:
  containers:
    - image:
      name:
      volumeMounts:
        - name: blob01
          mountPath: "/mnt/blob"
  volumes:
    - name: blob01
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc-blob
```

Now I logged into the pod and verified the files as below.
https://i.imgur.com/rIoU2DX.png

**Referrences:**

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-csi-blob-storage-provision?tabs=mount-nfs%2Csecret
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-blob-csi?tabs=NFS#before-you-begin
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support
4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support-how-to

Comment: But did you run the chmod from a shell script on a location mounted as a pv?